# Can I create salt keys in Wordpress without using the API?

Tags: php, python, wordpress, cryptography

I'm writing a script in python that helps me create a standard `wp-config.php` file with custom data, when it comes to **salt keys** I can of course generate a 64 characters random string but I'm wondering if the salts must be related each other, hence generated only using the Wordpress API (https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) or if I can just bloat any random string.

In this case, can I use any symbol to generate it or some symbols are excluded? What if I simply remove the salt keys, will Wordpress re-generate those the first time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want for the salt keys : they are just random strings and they are not related to each others so any random string generator will be fine.

As far as I know, there are no restrictions on the characters used in the salt

Comment: thank you! Do you know if there is some restriction in symbols that can be used for DB Password instead?

Comment: passwords are hashed to be stored so you can use everything you want, it will always end up as an alphanumeric string

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it's quite easy. I would suggest converting the original `wp_generate_password()` function, which WordPress uses to generate salt, into Python. I've done the same in bash, see the comparison.

Here's the [original wp_generate_password() function in PHP](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) which WordPress uses to generate salt values:

```php
function wp_generate_password( $length = 12, $special_chars = true, $extra_special_chars = false ) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    if ( $special_chars ) {
        $chars .= '!@#$%^&*()';
    }
    if ( $extra_special_chars ) {
        $chars .= '-_ []{}<>~`+=,.;:/?|';
    }
 
    $password = '';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $password .= substr( $chars, wp_rand( 0, strlen( $chars ) - 1 ), 1 );
    }
}
```

Here's the same [wp_generate_password() function rewritten to bash](https://github.com/timofey-drozhzhin/wp-generate-salt/blob/main/wp-generate-salt.sh):

```bash
function wp_generate_password() {
  # Args
  local length="$(test $1 && echo $1 || echo 12 )"
  local special_chars="$(test $2 && echo $2 || echo 1 )"
  local extra_special_chars="$(test $3 && echo $3 || echo 0 )"

  chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
  [[ $special_chars != 0 ]] && chars="$chars"'!@#$%^&*()'
  [[ $extra_special_chars != 0 ]] && chars="$chars"'-_ []{}<>~`+=,.;:/?|'

  password='';
  for i in $(seq 1 $length); do
  password="${password}${chars:$(( RANDOM % ${#chars} )):1}"
  done

  echo "$password"
}
```

You can then generate the salt values by running `wp_generate_password( 64, true, true )` in PHP or `wp_generate_password 64 1 1` in bash.